# convert List[Tuple2[A,B]] to Tuple2[Seq[A],Seq[B]]

Tags: list, scala, transform, tuples, seq

Stuck here, trying to convert a List of case class tuples to a tuple of sequences and multi-assign the result.

```
val items = repo.foo.list // gives me a List[(A,B)]
```

I can pull off multi-assignment like so:

```
val(a,b) = (items.map(_._1).toSeq, items.map(_._2).toSeq)
```

but it would be nicer to do in 1 step, along the lines of:

```
val(a,b) = repo.foo.list.map{case(a,b) => (a,b)}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood the question correctly. Maybe `unzip` works for what you want?

Here is a link with some examples: http://daily-scala.blogspot.de/2010/03/unzip.html

Comment: +1 yes, keep forgetting that one ;-) Now, how to convert to Seq all in 1 operation (see updated question)

Comment: yes, was asking about converting to Seq (unzip gives me a List). Doesn't matter though, compiler seems to silently convert List to Seq for methods that require a Seq

Comment: There's no silent conversion beyond simple inheritance, as List extends Seq (indirectly through LinearSeq).

Comment: @KristianDomagala right, convert was not the right word, perhaps viewed as would have been more clear

Answer (score 0):

For a more general case you can look at [product-collections](https://github.com/marklister/product-collections).  A `CollSeqN` is both a `Seq[TupleN[A1..An]]` and a `TupleN[Seq[A1..An]]`

In your example you could extract the Seqs like so:

```
items._1
items._2
...
```