# Variable multi-assign via unzip on List[( (A,B),(C,D) )], or List[(A,B,C,D)]

Tags: scala, list, tuples, transform

In regard to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13006973/185840) I was able to multi-assign via `unzip` on a `List[(A,B)]`

However, now I'm finding a need to multi-assign on either a `List[( (A,B),(C,D) )]` or a `List[(A,B,C,D)]`

I see that there is an unzip for pairs, and an unzip3 for triplets, but how to destructure a pair of `Tuple2` OR a single `Tuple4` so as to multi-assign? I'll adapt the collection type below accordingly, but whichever one works for 1-step multi-assignment is fine.

```
// foo can be a List[(A,B,C,D)] OR List[( (A,B),(C,D) )]
val(a,b,c,d) = foo.unzip
```

This works but is hacked

```
val(a,b,c_d) foo.unzip3 // foo is a List[(A,B,(C,D))]
```

because I wind up having to `c_d._1` and `c_d._2`, the very notation I'm trying to avoid by multi-assigning variables

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I agree that the question needs some work. For example, `List` only has one type parameter, so what you mean by `List[(A, B), (C, D)]` is a little unclear—as is the static type of `foo`, since it clearly can't be both `List[(A, B, C, D)]` and `List[((A, B), (C, D))]`.

Comment: Thanks, the "or" means either one "List[(A,B,C,D)]" or "List[((A,B),(C,D))]" will do.  The basic issue appears to be that you have to work with pairs or triplets when unzip'ing, and multi-assigning beyond a single Tuple2 or Tuple3 becomes difficult if not impossible AFAIK

Comment: But the least upper bound of `(A, B, C, D)` and `((A, B), (C, D))` is `Product`, so `foo` would have to be `List[Product]`, which is pretty much useless. Unless you just mean you want the same syntax for both—not that you literally have one variable that can be either?

Comment: I can make the result type (from a database query) whatever I want it to be. List[Product] is indeed useless,, thus the question. When working with a List[Tuple2] you can unzip, multi-assign, and the types are preserved. As soon as you go to List of Tuple4 or List containing a pair of Tuple2, types are lost. I can go with a List[Tuple3] result and unzip3 on that, just hacked since the 3rd param becomes a hash of C & D which I don't like

Comment: +1 just to balance the unexplained downvote, whoever it was cast by.

Comment: Deleted my post because @senia has posted a better answer that uses a similar technique.

Comment: Thanks @missingfaktor the unexplained downvotes are no fun (tried to +1 you for the obvious effort on your post, but you deleted the answer)

Comment: +1 by the way, after the edits.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this goes without saying, but there's a simple way to do this if you don't mind multiple steps:

```
val foo = List((1 -> "w", 'x -> 2.0), (101 -> "Y", 'Z -> 3.0))
val (p, q) = foo.unzip
val (a, b) = p.unzip
val (c, d) = p.unzip
```

If you really want a one-liner, you'll have to resort to something like Scalaz, which provides a `Bifunctor` instance for tuples that lets you write this, for example:

```
 import scalaz._, Scalaz._

 val ((a, b), (c, d)) = foo.unzip.bimap(_.unzip, _.unzip)
```

This is essentially the same as the version above, but having `bimap` lets us do everything in one line.

Comment: +1, yes, I already did the 2-step approach, just a sucker for 1-liners. re: bimap, at some point I need to dive into Scalaz, clearly a lot of useful stuff there.

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need any implicit conversions here.  The trick is to take advantage of custom extractor objects, like so:

```
object Unzipped4 {

  def unapply[A, B, C, D](ts: List[(A, B, C, D)]): Some[(List[A], List[B], List[C], List[D])] =
    Some((ts map _._1, ts map _._2, ts map _._3, ts map _._4))

}
```

You then use it like this:

```
val Unzipped4(as, bs, cs, ds) = foo
```

You could actually expand this to an arbitrary `Product` by using the dynamic access methods on that class, but you'd lose some type safety in the process.

Comment: +1, your handle rings a bell and I remember why, out-of-the-box thinking

Comment: `ts map _._1` needs to be written as `ts.map(_._1)` or `ts map (_._1)`

Answer (score 2):

As there are only `unzip` and `unzip3`, why don't you just write an extension for that? Something like this should work (2.10 code):

```
implicit class Unzip4[A,B,C,D](val xs: List[(A,B,C,D)]) extends AnyVal {
  def unzip4: (List[A], List[B], List[C], List[D]) = xs.foldRight[(List[A], List[B], List[C], List[D])]((Nil,Nil,Nil,Nil)) { (x, res) =>
    val (a,b,c,d) = x
    (a :: res._1, b :: res._2, c :: res._3, d :: res._4)
  }
}
```

Comment: +1, nice, that is clearly more elegant than my working solution with Tuple3/unzip3 approach. On 2.9.2, sounds like this won't fly unless on 2.10

Comment: You just have to create all the implicit conversion stuff yourself

Comment: It's a one-off problem, producing a schedule of games where container case class has 4 Seq properties, 2 of which are case classes, 1 an Int and the last a String. Normally I can map through a List[TupleN] and create a List of container case class (don't enjoy "tuple._n" notation), but not so easily in this case, thus the unzip4 request

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own `unzip4` method.

```
import scala.collection._
import generic._

class Unzipper[A, CC[X] <: GenTraversable[X]](s: GenericTraversableTemplate[A, CC]) {
  def unzip4[A1, A2, A3, A4](implicit asQuad: A => (A1, A2, A3, A4)): (CC[A1], CC[A2], CC[A3], CC[A4]) = {
    val b1 = s.genericBuilder[A1]
    val b2 = s.genericBuilder[A2]
    val b3 = s.genericBuilder[A3]
    val b4 = s.genericBuilder[A4]
    for (e <- s) {
      val (a, b, c, d) = asQuad(e)
      b1 += a
      b2 += b
      b3 += c
      b4 += d
    }
    (b1.result, b2.result, b3.result, b4.result)
  }
}

implicit def toUnzipper[A, CC[X] <: GenTraversable[X]](s: GenericTraversableTemplate[A, CC]) = new Unzipper(s)
implicit def t2t2Tot4[A1, A2, A3, A4](tt: ((A1, A2), (A3, A4))) = tt match { case ((a, b), (c, d)) => (a, b, c, d) }
implicit def t1t3Tot4[A1, A2, A3, A4](tt: (A1, (A2, A3, A4))) = tt match { case (a, (b, c, d)) => (a, b, c, d) }
implicit def t3t1Tot4[A1, A2, A3, A4](tt: ((A1, A2, A3), A4)) = tt match { case ((a, b, c), d) => (a, b, c, d) }
```

Usage:

```
scala> List((1, 2, 3, 4)).unzip4
res0: (List[Int], List[Int], List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(1),List(2),List(3),List(4))

scala> List((1, 2) -> (3, 4)).unzip4
res1: (List[Int], List[Int], List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(1),List(2),List(3),List(4))

scala> List(1 -> (2, 3, 4)).unzip4
res2: (List[Int], List[Int], List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(1),List(2),List(3),List(4))

scala> List((1, 2, 3) -> 4).unzip4
res3: (List[Int], List[Int], List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(1),List(2),List(3),List(4))
```

Comment: +1, ok, verified in console, works. Was hoping could pull off with existing collections library, but apparently not...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the great other answers I played around and thought about having nested and arity-generic unzips. My approach uses type classes and loses arity and type safety like `productIterator` on tuples. Perhaps someone can adapt it using `HList` from [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) for the rescue. One also have to implement the pimp my library to use `unzip` on collections to return the proper (same) collection type `unzip` was called on and to get rid of `Iterable`, but I omitted this here to only show the idea of nested arity-generic unzips. Perhaps one can use some kind of *LowerPriorityImplicits* to implicitly convert any `A` to `Unzippable[A,A]` if there isn´t a concrete implicit conversion to Unzippable for a given type.

```
trait Unzippable[T, +Super] {
  def unzip(t: T): Iterable[Super]
}

implicit object IntUnzippable extends Unzippable[Int, Int] { def unzip(i: Int) = Seq(i) }
implicit object BooleanUnzippable extends Unzippable[Boolean, Boolean] { def unzip(b: Boolean) = Seq(b) }
implicit object StringUnzippable extends Unzippable[String, String] { def unzip(s: String) = Seq(s) }

implicit def Tuple2Unzippable[Super, A <: Super, B <: Super, S, S1 <: S, S2 <: S](implicit ev1: Unzippable[A, S1], ev2: Unzippable[B, S2]) = new Unzippable[(A, B), S] {
  def unzip(t: (A, B)): Iterable[S] = ev1.unzip(t._1) ++ ev2.unzip(t._2)
}

def unzip[A, Super](i: Iterable[A])(implicit ev: Unzippable[A, Super]): Iterable[Iterable[Super]] = i.map(ev.unzip).transpose

object MyTuple3 {
  def unapply[X](i: Iterable[X]): Option[(X, X, X)] = if (i.size != 3) return None else Some((i.head, i.drop(1).head, i.last))
}

val list = (1, ("A", true)) :: (2, ("B", false)) :: (3, ("C", true)) :: Nil
val MyTuple3(nums, letters, bools) = unzip(list)
println((nums, letters, bools)) // (List(1, 2, 3),List(A, B, C),List(true, false, true))
```

Comment: Basically +1'ing all the answers as, at a minimum, so far they all show a good deal of effort, not to mention expertise of the creators. As to whether or not I grok the intricacies, at this time, no ;-) Funny how a simple question (minus 1'd to start no less) peaked the interest of several scala heavies...